# Make one class appear on another class hover

Tags: html, css, web, hover, opacity

Hello all I am trying to make a full-width bar of images, and when one image is hovered, I want text about that image to appear below the bar. So far I have the following html and css:

```
<div class="everything-container">
  <div class="pic-container">
    <img class="pic one" src="http://homeinspectioncarync.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/glenn-e1464714419457.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="info-container">
    <div class="name">
      <p class="glenn name">Glenn</p>
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      <p class="glenn title">Part Owner/ Senior Inspector</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bio">
      <p class="glenn bio">My name is Glenn and I am amazing.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.everything-container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.pic-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
.info-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.name {
  height: 400px;
  width: 25%;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 120%;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
.title {
  height: 400px;
  width: 20%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 90%;
  text-decoration: italic;
  color: grey;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
.bio {
  height: 400px;
  width: 55%;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  float: left;
  font-size: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
.pic {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

I gave one of my images the class of "one" and when i hover it i want anything with a class of "glenn" to appear. Using .one:hover .glenn { *stuff* } did not work. Is this possible to do? Thank you!

Comment: With your HTML structure, you'll have to use JS, or some hack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid this is the closest you can get without javascript:

```
<div class="everything one">
  <div class="image">
   <img src="..." />
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    Name
    Title
    Details
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.everything .info {
 opacity: 0;
}

.everything:hover .info {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: I dont have much experience with JS, would something like this be easy?

Comment: This is the non-javascript approach - drop it in your code, see what it does.

Comment: This will work now because I only have one picture, but when i add more pictures, i dont want the info for one to come up upon me hovering over another.

Comment: this is a single block. One image, one `.info` block. So long as you add another block with it's own image and `.info` block, the two won't interfere with each other.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make ".one:hover .glenn" work you need that everything with class 'glenn' to be inside of element with class 'one'.

If you are not able to achieve this you probably have to go with javascript.

Comment: I dont have much experience in javasript, would something like this be easy?

Comment: @skyleguy, if you are using jquery add to your page:

`<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".pic-container").mouseover(function(){
         $(".info-container").show()
     });
     $(".pic-container").mouseover(function(){
         $(".info-container").show();
     });
     $(".pic-container").mouseleave(function(){
         $(".info-container").hide();
     });
});
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

```
.info-container {
    display: none;
}   

.pic-container:hover + .info-container {
    display: block;
}
```

This is the easiest way:

- Because you don't need JavaScript
- Because it works with your HTML, no configuration needed.